# Magnific Popup - popup within a popup. How to make "close" go to previous popup?

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I've got a fairly basic setup:

```
 $('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
        type: 'ajax',
        callbacks: {
            ajaxContentAdded: function () {
                $('.image-link').magnificPopup();
            };
        }
});
```

What I'd like to do is have the close event of the "image-link" popup go back to the original popup. MY first thought is to grab the original element and maybe pass it to the 2nd popup, then bind the close event to that element... so that when it closes, it just automatically popsup the original one.

Has anyone else done anything like this? Is there a better way to possibly do this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the only way to achieve what you want is to take the original element and reopen it. But passing it to 2nd popup's `close` callback won't give you anything, since it will never be called. `MagnificPopup` will not fire `open` event if popup is already opened, because there is actually only one instance of `Magnific Popup Object`. What you can do is to check if `currItem` is equal to 1st popup's item.

```
var childOpened,
    parentItem,
    $parent = $('.ajax-popup-link');
$parent.magnificPopup({
    type: 'ajax',
    callbacks: {
        open: function () {
            // triggered only when 1st popup opens
            // save 1st popup's item
            parentItem = this.currItem;
            // will not register new callbacks even if we pass them
            $('.image-link').magnificPopup();
        },
        close: function () {
            // will be called twice, since we opened popup twice
            // do not move to `afterClose`. `currItem` is not available there
            childOpened = (this.currItem !== parentItem);
        },
        afterClose: function () {
            if (childOpened) {
                // should be in `afterClose` to avoid conflicts
                // with previous popup opening
                $parent.magnificPopup('open');
            }
        }
    }
});
```